# Jenkins Job DSL: how do you set "Default subview"?

Tags: jenkins-job-dsl

I am trying to create nested tabs with a Jenkins Job DSL Groovy script.  It creates them, but I can find no way to set the "Default subview" in the DSL API.  It does not appear to display the tabs correctly until I do this.  Once I manually, change that default, it displays correctly.  Here is the code:

```
nestedView(viewName) {
  views {
    listView("Builds (Staging)") {
      jobs {
        name(buildJobName)
      }
      columns {
                status()
                weather()
                name()
                lastSuccess()
                lastFailure()
                lastDuration()
                buildButton()
              }
    }
    listView("Deployments (Staging)") {
      jobs {
        name(deployJobName)
      }
      columns {
                status()
                weather()
                name()
                lastSuccess()
                lastFailure()
                lastDuration()
                buildButton()
              }
    }
  }
}
```

[Original view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1F6Cr.png)

[Corrected view after manually changing Default subview in Edit View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WfN9B.png)

Answer (score 3):

You can use a [Configure Block](https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin/wiki/The-Configure-Block) to any missing config XML elements.

```
nestedView('test') {
  views {
    listView("Builds (Staging)") {
      jobs {
        name('foo')
      }
      columns {
        status()
        weather()
        name()
      }
    }
    listView("Deployments (Staging)") {
      jobs {
        name('bar')
      }
      columns {
        status()
        weather()
        name()
      }
    }
  }
  configure { view ->
    view / defaultView('Builds (Staging)')
  }
}
```

Please file a [ticket](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS/component/16720) or open a [pull request](https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin/pulls) for any missing DSL methods.

Answer (score 0):

If you happen to be configuring views under a folder, you can set it there.

```
folder(abc)
{   
    views {
        listView('foo') {
        primaryView('foo')
    }   
}
```

It looks like it's available since version 1.36